# Fetch data with SmartClient LGPL version

Tags: smartclient

I want to use LGPL version of smart client to connect to my own server. I want the SmartClient to send a fetch request (with operation type, range etc) — I'll handle the rest. But I can't force SmartClient to do it. All I managed to do is force it to send a simple GET request. What should I add?

My code:

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <SCRIPT>var isomorphicDir="../isomorphic/";</SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/system/modules/ISC_Core.js></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/system/modules/ISC_Foundation.js></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/system/modules/ISC_Containers.js></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/system/modules/ISC_Grids.js></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/system/modules/ISC_Forms.js></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/system/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT SRC=../isomorphic/skins/SmartClient/load_skin.js></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <SCRIPT>

    isc.DataSource.create({
        ID:"countries",
        dataURL:"countries_small.js",
        fields:[
            {name:"name", type:"text", primaryKey:true},
            {name:"population"},
        ]
    });

    isc.ListGrid.create({
        width: "100%",
        height: 50,

        dataSource: "countries",
        drawAllMaxCells:0,
        dataPageSize:1,
        drawAheadRatio:1,
        showAllRecords:false,
        autoFetchData: true
    });

    </SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i found a solution. the clue is to use RestDataSource.

```js
isc.RestDataSource.create({
    ID:"countriesDS",
    dataFormat:"json",
    dataURL: "partial.js",
    operationBindings:[
                       {operationType:"fetch", dataProtocol:"postParams"}
                    ],
   fields:[
           {title:"Name", name:"name", type:"text", primaryKey:true},
           {title:"Population", name:"population", type:"text"}
       ]
});

isc.ListGrid.create({
    width: "100%",
    height: 60,
    dataFetchMode:"paged",
    dataSource: "countriesDS",
    dataPageSize:2,
    canEdit:true,
    drawAheadRatio:1,
    showAllRecords:false,    
    autoFetchData: true
});
```

and then, response may look like:

```js
{ response:{
    status:0,
    startRow:0,
    endRow:1,
    totalRows:2,
    data:[
          {name:"Italy", population:"12"},
          {name:"Germany", population:"121"} 
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is define your URLs for the other operations:

replace your dataURL in the dataSource object with individual bindings:

```
operationBindings:[  
{operationType:"fetch", dataURL:"<fetch URL>"},
{operationType:"add",dataProtocol:"postParams",  dataURL:"<insert URL>"},
{operationType:"update",dataProtocol:"postParams", dataURL:"<Update URL>"},
{operationType:"remove",dataProtocol:"postParams", dataURL:"<delete URL>"}]
```

Set an ID you grid and make it editable:

```
ID:"MyGrid"
canEdit: true,
editEvent: "click"
```

It should fire the update request when you move off the row.

Add buttons for new row and delete row with the following commands:

```
isc.IButton.create({title:"New",click:"MyGrid.startEditingNew()"});
isc.IButton.create({title:"Delete",click:"MyGrid.removeData()"});
```

Your Add URL should receive the request once you move off the row.  The delete once you press the button.

I hope that's helpful.